# How to test directive in link phase?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-mocha

Here is some Javascript that makes a call to jqLite's `trigger` inside the `link` function of an AngularJS directive.

```
angular.
  module('myApp').
  directive('myDirective',
    function($timeout) {
      return {
        link: function(scope) {

          scope.resetChosenElements = function() {
            $timeout(function() { 
                $('[chosen]').trigger('chosen:updated'); 
            }, 0);
          }

          scope.resetChosenElements();          

        }
      };
    }
  );
```

How can I write a test that checks that `trigger` is called when the directive is created without spying on `$.trigger`? (I don't want to spy on `$.trigger` because that catches all calls made to it, including those form other directives).

Is there a way to spy on the `element` argument that can be passed to `link`?

EDIT: My comment about spying on `element` seems to be causing confusion. I was only implying that if the solution required adding `element` to the arguments passed to `link` then that would be fine. However currently I have no use for it otherwise, which is why it's excluded from the argument list.

Comment: Your link function doesn't have the `element` argument. Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelBenford it can if that makes a difference.

Comment: Well, you asked "Is there a way to spy on the element argument that can be passed to link?", so I assumed your directive did need that argument.

Answer (score 1):

Rathen that mock the `trigger` function you can spy the `element`'s event function, as [@Michael Benford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349152/michael-benford) said you are not using `element` in your code example, seems confusing considering your question any way:

This example is using [ChaiJS](http://chaijs.com/) as assertion tool and  [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/docs) as spies/stubs/mocks library You should add a `spy` on `element` `customEvent`

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    el = angular.element('<elementTemplateTag></elementTemplateTag>');
    compile(elm)($scope);
    spy = sinon.spy(el, "customEvent"); // Add spy on the event call
}));

afterEach(function(){
 el.customEvent.restore(); //clean spy calls
});

it('element.customEvent() called once', function() {

    el.trigger('customEvent');
    $timeout.flush(); // release all timeouts

    expect(el.customEvent.calledOnce()).to.be.true;
});
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm hesitant to resort to creating new event types every time I discover some limitation in AngularJS. IMO no new events should be fired in the normal course of assembling the UI of an application for which the only listener would be a unit test.

Comment: The "customEvent" was just an example, you can spy on "click", "change", etc, any event listener which is bound to the event that you need